# Data separation from single column multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in single column like different sets:

**Original data**

```
Class: Country1
Object: State1
Description: DEsc1
Object: State2
Description: DEsc2
Object: State3
Description: DEsc3
Object: State4
Description: DEsc4

Class: Country2
Object: State1
Description: DEsc1
Object: State2
Description: DEsc2
Object: State3
Description: DEsc3
Object: State4
Description: DEsc4

Class: Country3
Object: State1
Description: DEsc1
Object: State2
Description: DEsc2
Object: State3
Description: DEsc3
Object: State4
Description: DEsc4

Class: Country4
Object: State1
Description: DEsc1
Object: State2
Description: DEsc2
Object: State3
Description: DEsc3
Object: State4
Description: DEsc4
```

```
I am looking for Excel VBA macro code , which will clean and organize my data.

**Expected Data**
```

```
Class       Object    Description <br/>
----------------------------------
Country1    State1    DEsc1
Country1    State2    DEsc2
Country1    State3    DEsc3
Country1    State4    DEsc4
Country2    State1    DEsc1
Country2    State2    DEsc2
Country2    State3    DEsc3
Country2    State4    DEsc4
Country3    State1    DEsc1
Country3    State2    DEsc2
Country3    State3    DEsc3
Country3    State4    DEsc4
Country4    State1    DEsc1
Country4    State2    DEsc2
Country4    State3    DEsc3
Country4    State4    DEsc4
```

```
Thanks In Advance!!
KP

[Please find the attached image]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/otSV1.jpg
```

Comment: A screenshot would be beneficial.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This looks very much like you just need a loop running down, check the start of each Value, and save some text to variables?

Comment: Thanks for the update Chronocidal !! I am new to excel vba and macros. It would be great can you provide a macro code.

Comment: It looks like your want the `State` information ignored in the output.  **Is this correct ??**

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowC As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim strCountry As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRowA Step 10

            strCountry = Mid(.Range("A" & i).Value, InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value, ":") + 2, Len(.Range("A" & i).Value) - (InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value, ":") + 1))

            For y = 2 To LastRowA Step 2

                LastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

                If .Range("A" & y).Value <> "" Then
                    .Range("C" & LastRowC + 1).Value = strCountry
                    .Range("D" & LastRowC + 1).Value = "Object" & Mid(.Range("A" & y).Value, InStr(1, .Range("A" & y).Value, "te") + 2, Len(.Range("A" & y).Value) - (InStr(1, .Range("A" & y).Value, "te") + 1))
                    .Range("E" & LastRowC + 1).Value = Mid(.Range("A" & y + 1).Value, InStr(1, .Range("A" & y + 1).Value, ":") + 2, Len(.Range("A" & y + 1).Value) - (InStr(1, .Range("A" & y + 1).Value, ":") + 1))
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next y

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Image:**

[image]